# Car Racing Through Grid Algorithm Puzzle

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'm working through a problem in an algorithms book offered by a nearby university. The following problem is about graphing algorithms (Kruskal's Algorithm, BFS, DFS, Prim's Algorithm). I've been working on it for a few days now and I'm stuck.

The problem is as follows:

> Consider a computer game about racing cars in 2D. Your car is a pixel and the course is encoded as a set of valid pixels on an n × n screen: you’re given a 2D array where you can look up any pixel to see if it’s valid. Your objective is to get from a given start position to a given end position as fast as possible.
>
> Here are the rules:
>
> - Time is measured in unit steps
> - As mentioned, you begin at some start position with zero velocity
> - At every time step you can modify your horizontal velocity
>     by 1, or keep it the same. The same holds independently for vertical velocity. So if at a particular time you are at pixel *(x, y)* and already have velocity *(vx, vy)*, then at the next time step you will be at position *(x + vx, y + vy)*, after which each component of your velocity may change by ±1 if you wish.
> - You’re not allowed to shoot through the end position with arbitrary velocity. You must stop there to pick up your trophy.
> - At every time step your car must be at a valid pixel, but also between steps you must not drive over invalid pixels. To help with this last part, you’re given a table, *T*, of pixel pairs, where for each pair there is a bit letting you know if it’s legal to travel from one pixel to the other in a straight line. So in constant time you can you can look up any pair to see if moving directly from one to the other is OK.
>
> Formulate this game as a graph problem and describe how to find the optimal route for any given race course. What is the time complexity of your algorithm?

What I've gotten so far is to represent nodes in the graph as velocities (*n<sup>2</sup>* of them) and to represent edges between nodes as changes in velocity. Also, as there exists invalid locations, I was thinking there must be some way to weight the edges so as to run Kruskal's Algorithm on them.

Comment: Please edit your question to fix the formatting. For example, use a bulleted list for the rules. That huge paragraph is very difficult to read.

Comment: *represent nodes in the graph as velocities (n^2 of them) and to represent edges between nodes as changes in velocity* What is the logic behind this? Why not assuming pixels are nodes and the path between pixels are edges?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to define the graph as an unweighted graph and with following definition of vertices and edges:

- its vertices are the pairs of valid pixels that represent legal straight-line travels, as defined in table T. The number of vertices thus corresponds to the size of table T, i.e. *O(n<sup>4</sup>)*. The vertices would include zero-distance travels as well, i.e. where the pixel pair is a repetition of the same pixel.

  However, we can reduce the number of vertices by noting that there is a maximum velocity, in either direction, that can be attained when starting with a velocity of 0 and will not lead to car-crashes on the grid boundary. In one dimension the maximum velocity can only evolve from 0 to 1, to 2, to 3, in one step after the other. As the car cannot go further than *n* pixels in one direction, and should be able to also stop in time, we can find that the velocity in one direction should never be greater than *sqrt(n)*.

  For example, this accelerating and then breaking could give the sum of these velocities: 1+2+3+4+5+4+3+2+1 = 25. If *n* = 25, then the car would have traversed the whole grid (in one dimension), with a maximum velocity of 5. Any greater velocity would have led to a crash.

  So the interesting pixel pairs have horizontal *and* vertical distances between them that are both less than or equal to *sqrt(n)*. This means for a given pixel, there are at most *sqrt(n)*sqrt(n)*, i.e. *n* other pixels to combine it with. As there are *n<sup>2</sup>* pixels, we have *O(n<sup>3</sup>)* pairs (vertices) to consider.
- its edges connect vertices (i.e. pixel pairs) that can be consecutively travelled. By consequence

  - two connected vertices represent two pixel pairs that have (at least) one pixel in common, i.e. the pixel where the first travel unit ends and the second one starts;
  - These vertices have at most 9 neighbors, as during the drive the x-velocity can change by either -1, 0, or +1 (3 options), and the same holds for the y-velocity, giving 9 possibilities.

There are two special vertices in that graph:

- The one that corresponds to the (start, start) pixel pair, as this represents the initial state (0 velocity at the start pixel)
- The one that corresponds to the (target, target) pixel pair, as this represents the target state (0 velocity at the target pixel)

The problem can then be formulated as finding the shortest path between those two vertices.

The time complexity for the single sourced shortest path problem in an [unweighted graph is *O(E+V)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Unweighted_graphs), which in this particular problem is *O(9V+V)*, is *O(V)*, is *O(n<sup>3</sup>)*. This algorithm is a BFS in which you track the paths of length 1, then extend all these to length 2 (pruning where you get to an already visited vertex), ...etc, until you hit the target vertex. The path with which you hit it is a shortest path.